# How to define membership of sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Suppose we have a sequence $s$ defined as a function from a finite von Neumann ordinal. We take the image of $s$ to be its terms. How can I most naturally define a membership relation $\eta$ such $b\eta s$ iff $b$ is one of the terms of $s$?

Comment: Zermelo ordinals (I don't know what an *infinite* Zermelo ordinal would be) have only one element, so they don't work well as the domains of functions. I suspect you'll want the domains to be instead *downwards-closed sets of Zermelo ordinals* (e.g. $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$)? Incidentally, this is one reason to prefer von Neumann ordinals.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You are right, it was the von Neumann ordinals I had in mind! I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @NoahSchweber $\omega$ in the Zermelo way is defined as the union of all predecessors.

Comment: Of course, on some interpretations the question is unusually easy to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on particular forms of domains is actually a red herring here, if I understand correctly.

A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is in particular a subset of $X\times Y$. The range of $f$ is the set of second coordinates of elements of $f$. So, for example, if we're using Kuratowski's pairing notion $$\langle a,b\rangle = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\},$$ we can pick out the second coordinate of a set $c$ which happens to be an ordered pair as the unique $b$ such that

- $\{b\}\not\in c$, but
- there is some $a$ such that $\{a,b\}\in c$.

Formulating this in the language of set theory yields the following definition of "$b$ is the left coordinate of $c$" *(note that if $c$ is not an ordered pair, this will behave weirdly, but we don't care)*:

$$\forall x[(x\in c\wedge \color{red}{\forall y, z(y\in x\wedge z\in x\implies y=z))}\rightarrow x\not=b]$$ $$\wedge$$ $$\exists y, z[y\not=b\wedge y\in z\wedge b\in z\wedge z\in c].$$

*Annotation: the red clause says "$x$ has at most one element," the point being that $b$ can't be that $x$ since only the first coordinate of $c$ is contained in a set with at most one element which is contained in $c$*

---

Incidentally, specifying the domain $X$ actually doesn't obviously help, without the *further* constraint that $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ (since if they have nonempty intersection we still need to talk about first vs. second coordinates).

Comment: I guess the simplest definition would be $b\eta s\leftrightarrow\exists n(<n,b>\in s)$. But it seems that we are dealing with different problems and that my question was unusually trivial. It was incidental to some other things I think about.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal Well, your definition has an abbreviation in it - namely, the $\langle\rangle$ - which *when fully unwound* yields what I've written above, essentially. If you're allowing yourself to use it as a primitive, though, of course that works.